# How to adjusting border size according to text within?

Tags: css

I'm setting up the scoreboard display for my rock paper scissors game (Win:Draw:Lose), but if the results go up too high it is displayed over multiple rows. Where/How would I implement something to make the width longer? Ideally, having a function of some sort to make the border width longer when the text is about to go over to the next row would be best.

[image: Scoreboard normal]

[image: Scoreboard after WDL of 10]

[image: Scoreboard with long width]

Having a big border width to counter this problem looks ugly and not very good maintainability.

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: please add your html and css code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: [JSFIDDLE link](https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/ZZeBXj)

```css
body {
  background: #202020;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container-score {
  text-align: center;
  background: #3b4675;
  padding: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

.score {
  padding: 16px 48px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.title {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 16px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-score">
  <div class="title">
    <p>WIN : DRAW : LOSS </p>
  </div>
  <div class="score">
    <p>10: 10: 10</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

(please add your code while asking a question so that we can know what's wrong and help)
(here I'm guessing you used fixed `width` property to set the width of the scoreboard)

You should remove the `width` property from the scoreboard, use `min-width` instead. Also, add `white-space: nowrap;` to ensure the score will keep in 1 line.

So that if the needed width is less than a certain amount, the width will be min-width. But if it needs more space, as in your example, it will extend to fit it's content.

You can read more about min-width [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).

Comment: I'll make sure to add my code in my next question sorry. The link you provided helped with my problem "width: fit-content;"
I did run into a couple of other problems but AKNair's answer helped a lot. Thank you both for fast response time and I'm sure I'll be using this site again <3